# Dozer map Text to String

Tags: google-app-engine, dozer

I'm using GWT and GAE for my project. I'm using data transfer objects and dozer to move data between client and server.  Dozer had been working great, but I have some classes that need to store text that is over 500 characters, so I must use com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text datatype in my server side object, but a regular String in my client side object.  How do I map these two types using dozer? I know somehow I can specify an XML file, but how do I write that XML file?

Comment: Check [this link](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mappings.html). There you should be able to find the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

specify a mapping between both the datatypes as below. Dozer will use it at run-time to convert.

```
<mapping>
  <class-a>com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text</class-a>
  <class-b>java.lang.String</class-b>
</mapping>
```

In case you don't know how to use config file ,
 In your code,

```
DozerMapper beanMapper = new DozerMapper();
beanMapper.mapping(new ArrayList<String>(){
 {
    add("name Of the dozer mapping file");
 }
});
```